# Cannot fetch / read data from firebase real-time database to UITableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I am able to successfully write data from my application to my firebase real-time database. I cannot retrieve the data and display it in a UIViewController.

I have search stack, YouTube and firebase docs and no luck. I printed out the count and it returns 0. I believe the For loop isn't iterating or its not appending to my array correctly. I have trie force wrapping and unwrapping refRepairs, and placing databaseHandle in from of it.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refRepairs = Database.database().reference().child("repairs");

    //observing the data changes
    refRepairs!.child("repairs").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.repairList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for repairs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let repairObject = repairs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let brand  = repairObject?["brand"]
                let id  = repairObject?["id"]
                let modelNumber = repairObject?["modelNumber"]

                //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                let repair = RepairModel(id: id as! String?, brand: brand as! String?, modelNumber: modelNumber as! String?)

                //appending it to list
                print(snapshot.childrenCount)

                self.repairList.append(repair)
            }

            //reloading the tableview
            self.doListTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

I made the changes and it was working!!! Now, I am trying to add records to the database by uid, and I have successfully done it. Now I have the same problem where I can't display the records. I printed the count and it returns 1 record which is correct. Here is the new code.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refRepairs = Database.database().reference().child("repairs");

    //observing the data changes
    //refRepairs!.child("uid").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        //observing the data changes
        refRepairs!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.repairList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for repairs in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let repairObject = repairs.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let brand  = repairObject?["brand"]
                let uid = repairObject?["uid"]
                let id  = repairObject?["id"]
                let modelNumber = repairObject?["modelNumber"]

                //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                let repair = RepairModel(uid: uid as! String?, id: id as! String?, brand: brand as! String?, modelNumber: modelNumber as! String?)

                //appending it to list
                print(snapshot.childrenCount)

                self.repairList.append(repair)
            }

            //reloading the tableview
            self.doListTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Also, I have double checked to make sure my IBOutlets, delegate and datasources are connected from storyboard to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking another second child called repairs when you are "observing the data changes". Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  refRepairs = Database.database().reference().child("repairs");

  //observing the data changes
  refRepairs!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    ...
```

If that don't work. Use the observeSingleEvent method from Firebase

Comment: Using the code above, can I add a field to display the cells by user ID? I dont want everyone to see what everyone added just what they added...

Comment: Yes. Your childs need to contain a reference with the UserID. So, when you fetch that child, only filter that fetch by UserID

Comment: great! I change my code and successfully added records into the database by userID. How do I adapt the code above only to display the uid?